# PHP redirect instead of proposing download

Tags: php, wordpress, export-to-csv

I'm having an issue with proposing a file to save (csv) on the click of a button on a wordpress site I'm creating. I have simplified my code to the bare minimum and it is still not working.

My template page code :

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Awesome Custom Page
*/

get_header(); ?>
<html>
<form style= "text-align:center;" name="getcsv" action="test.php"      method="post">
 <select id="ddl">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> <br/>
<input  name= "export_excel" type="submit" value="Extraire"/>
</form>
</html>
<?php get_footer();
```

And the test.php file has :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["export_excel"]))
{
header( 'Content-type: application/xls' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.xls"');
header( 'Expires: 0' );
header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
header( 'Pragma: public' ); 
$headers = array('Type of Activity', "Number of Activities", "Hours of         Instruction");
$row_1 = array($_POST['ddl'], $_POST['ddl'], $_POST['ddl']);
$output = implode(',',$headers);
$output.= "\n";
$output.= implode(',',$row_1);
$output.= "\n"; 
}
?>
```

When I click on the button, it redirects me from http://localhost/test/pagedetest to http://localhost/test/pagedetest/test.php and I of course get a 404 since that page was never created.

This is just a test case so I can build on it to make something a bit more complicated but even this is not working.

I tried using the fputcsv function instead on just a simple echo into php://output and using an ajax call instead of a form but that gave me nothing (no error or anything)

If anybody has an idea as to why this is happening, thanks in advance !

Sorry if it's a stupid question but my google-fu didn't turn up anything and I haven't been playing with either wordpress or PHP for long...

Cheers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`action="test.php"` will submit the form to a file called test.php within the current directory. I'm guessing your test.php is at http://localhost/test/test.php or http://localhost/test.php. Use the absolute path (`/test.php` or `/test/test.php`) as your action, and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your solution but no dice. I either get http://localhost/test/pagedetest/test/test.php or http://localhost/test.php as a redirect. What I don't understand is why it tries to change my url. If I do an Ajax call it would just treat the data I sent it and return what I want. Why would it do it differently here ?

Comment: Where is the test.php located? What redirects happen according to your browser's dev tools?

Comment: Ok what you said put me on the right track, wordpress apparently needs you explicitly need to specify the path with the get_template_uri function. 
Once you append that to the file name, it works just fine.
Thanks a bunch !